# Is there a way to display the computer name in cmd?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I want to display the name of my computer in CMD next to the directory I'm in, like how it is in the MacOS terminal or in the Ubuntu Terminal.

Comment: not sure exactly what you want but `set PROMPT=%COMPUTERNAME%-$P$G` might get you going.

Answer (score 2):

**For Command Line:**

As HelpingHand posted, you can use `set PROMPT=%COMPUTERNAME%-$P$G` in the command prompt terminal to set it temporarily.

To make it permanent, you need to create a new `string value` registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` named `autorun` and set the value of that key as `PROMPT=%COMPUTERNAME%-$P$G`.

The quickest way to create the key is from a Powershell prompt:

```powershell
New-ItemProperty -name Autorun -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\' -PropertyType String -Value 'PROMPT=%COMPUTERNAME%-$P$G' -Force
```

**For Powershell:**

Powershell is similar to Linux shells, in which you create a `profile.ps1` file that contains the commands you want to run. Where you create this file depends on who you want the profile to be viewed by, and the Powershell host you want to view that prompt in. (The Powershell terminal or the ISE). For the profile to apply to you in all hosts, it needs to be in `$Home\Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1`.

The `profile.ps1` file should contain:

```powershell
function Prompt
{
 $env:COMPUTERNAME + "\" + (Get-Location) + "> "
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need an elevated PS prompt to set the user’s own registry keys.

Comment: Ah, I expected that editing the registry at ALL would require elevated prompts.